# Unify normal estimation using PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, vcg

I used PCL (Point-cloud library) to triangulate a 3D point cloud. But the triangulation I got is not consistent. I get a similar situation as at question: [How to unify normal orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510054/how-to-unify-normal-orientation][1]).

But this code does not work well, I can't compile it. I get an exception within a function call:

```
vcg::tri::UpdateNormal<MyMesh>::PerFace(m)
```

Beside，VCG has been updated to a newer edition, and the original author edited the source code, so it won't work now.

Comment: What is the message of the exception you get within a function call `vcg::tri::UpdateNormal<MyMesh>::PerFace(m)`?